# OGC API Processes returns error 500 or 400

Tags: geoprocessing, ogc-api

I am testing the following OGC API endpoint on demo pygeoapi server
https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/processes/hello-world/jobs
following the [documentation page 32](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-processes/master/docs/18-062.pdf)

I post the following JSON body:

```
{
    "id": "dzed5zef45zfze",
    "inputs": {
        "literalInputId": 
            {
                "dataType": {
                    "name": "string"
                },
                "value": "Marsel"
            }
        
    },
    "outputs": {
        "literalOutputId": {
            "transmissionMode": "value"
        }
    },
    "response": "document",
    "mode": "sync"
}
```

with the following python command:

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/processes/hello-world/jobs', data=json.dumps(body))
>>> r
<Response [500]>
```

or

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/processes/hello-world/jobs', data=body)
>>> r
<Response [400]>
```

Comment: "documentation page 32" is a local link e.g `http://file///C:/Users/Stanusjl/Downloads/18-062.pdf` Change it please as it's difficult to understand otherwise

Comment: @ThomasG77 i fixed the link sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested without issue with

```py
import json
import requests

body = {"mode": "sync", "inputs":[{"id":"name","type":"text/plain","value":"hi there2"}, {"id":"message","type":"text/plain","value":"My message is superb"}]}
r = requests.post('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/processes/hello-world/jobs', data=json.dumps(body))

print(r.json())
```

I'm wondering where you got/deduced the payload you use.